# Android Dalvik Conversion Error while trying to run app

Tags: android, dalvik

i was working fine with the project i saved work and closed eclipse when i opened again for work and tried to runon emulator it is saying :

> > [2012-12-04 15:08:09 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: com/android/dx/util/FileUtils
> >     [2012-12-04 15:08:09 - TestApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: com/android/dx/util/FileUtils

i dont know why this coming help pls..

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: com/android/dx/util/FileUtils    TestApp     Unknown Android Packaging Problem

receving this error in Errors tab

Comment: i did'nt got what you want to tell..:(

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: com/android/dx/util/FileUtils TestApp  Unknown Android Packaging Problem

this is written in the problems tab

Comment: anybody answer plz.. i am stucked badly...

Comment: If @Nipun Gogia's answer doesn't help then try restarting your eclipse and emulator

Comment: i did but it did'nt worked......:/

Comment: I solved my problem by creating new project and copying all the code in new project and it worked for me at last...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just clean your project ....

in eclipse goto -->projects --> select clean --> select your project ( shows in popup )

Comment: i tried this one but not worked for me....:(

Comment: I solved my problem by creating new project and copying all the code in new project and it worked for me at last...:)

Comment: ok great.... in my case mine was working .... :)